# How to realod Andengine game activity?

Tags: android, andengine

How can I reload activity or game when I was completed a level in game? I am developing e a game using Andengine in android? Please any body ca  help me?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. Ask question related to games here

Answer (score 0):

If by "reload" you mean you want to tear down the engine and create a new one, that's probably not what you want to do. An activity in Android is a "single, focused thing that a user can do." In the case of a game, the activity runs from the point at which the user decides to play the game to the point the user decides to do something else. Next levels should be handled internally in the activity.

See more on activities here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

AndEngine is set up to be its own activity, so its not a good idea to restart the activity each time there is a next level. Instead, you ideally want to load all backgrounds/resources you need for each level by overriding onCreateResources, onCreateScene and onPopulateScene in the main AndEngine activity.

Then, you insert checks in the callbacks that are called whenever the user moves/interacts with the scene (such as in onAreaTouched) to detect whether a the user has "won" a level. If so, you change backgrounds, remove all the sprites from the last level, and instantiate new sprites for the new level.

This is too large a topic to give code samples, but it seems you might benefit from a more in-depth tutorial in AndEngine. One can be found here: http://andenginedevtutorial.blogspot.com/2012/11/first-project-andengine.html

(however, if you insist on reloading it, you should tear it down by calling finish(). You should have another activity that it backs out to, which can then start the activity again.)